# Cognitive service to identify consumer products?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

**Context:**
Currently some retailers offer their customers the option to upload a picture of some product. In response the customer receives a list of matching products.

**My scenario:**
I would like to be able to upload images of products, for example shoes, and receive a list of matching shoes.

**What I tried:**
I used the computer vision API for my specific scenario. I tried shoes, shirts, watches, bra's. 
The response is very accurate. It really identifies all the products well.

**My problem:**
The response of the computer vision API, although accurate, is not specific enough. With the response I can't really distinguish between two products of the same type. Usually only the accent colour is different in the response.

**My question:**
Do you know a way to use the cognitive services for consumer product identification?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know a way to use the cognitive services for consumer product
>   identification?

Yes, via [Custom Vision Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) combined with a [Custom Decision Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/custom-decision-service/)
Use it inside a Logic App to get the best results.

It's up to you how to tie them together based on your products.

Comment: I hoped an easier solution was available. But this is probably the way to go. Do you have experience using Azure for product identification? what's your opinion about the vision APIs from Google, Amazon, etc?